# Как определить процесс нагружающий цпу по нарастающей и сбрасывающийся в ноль раз в сутки

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, cpu, prometheus, ec2

На CPU имеем нагрузку  (сверху Network, снизу CPU)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
загрузка CPU резко стремится к нулю каждый день в районе 6:25-6:30, после снова начинает рост.

Сервер AWS EC2 Linux 2, на борту 
- PHP + Nginx + Redis
- Prometheus + node_exporter
- nodejs + pm2 + nginx_exporter

Может node_exporter или Prometheus создавать нагрузку на CPU?

Как точно идентифицировать процесс нагружающий CPU?

Comment: Как вариант, мониторить ваши процессы https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch-Agent-procstat-process-metrics.html

Answer (score 2):

В районе 0 часов зайдите в консоль и выдайте команду

```
top
```

Самый "прожорливый" процесс будет в верхней строчке отчёта.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте добавить задание в `cron` к примеру на каждые 10 минут с командой на подобии:

```
echo -e "`date +'%Y-%m-%d %T'` >>>>>\n `ps -eo pid,ppid,cmd,%cpu,%mem --sort=-%cpu | head -n 6`\n<<<<<"
```

Записать результат работы команды в файл, добавив в конце `>> file.log`, где file.log нужно имя файла, желательно путь к нему указывать от корневой системы `/`

результатом вывода будет ТОП 5 процессов использующих CPU, и будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
2020-03-27 09:09:48 >>>>>
   PID  PPID CMD                         %CPU %MEM
13230 13218 /root/.nvm/versions/node/v1  0.7  1.0
 5043  5039 redis-server 127.0.0.1:6379  0.2  0.1
 6818     1 /usr/sbin/mysqld             0.2  2.2
10356 10305 java -D[Standalone] -server  0.2  2.3
 5044  5039 laravel-echo-server          0.1  0.2
<<<<<
```

Для изменения количества строк замените цифру 6 в части `head -n 6` на нужную.

так же полезно будет почитать `man ps`